# How to remove an animated view after animation ends in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using an right to left moving animation for a RelativeLayout.

I tried to set the Visibility to 'GONE' for the Layout in the `onAnimationEnd()`,but it is not working. The animated view is still there in the place where it stops.

This is the code I used:

Creating animation for right to left:

```
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,-rlImages.getWidth()/2,0,0);
animate.setDuration(1000);
animate.setFillAfter(true);
```

Setting the animation to layout:

```
centre_leftanimate.startAnimation(animate);
```

Adding listeners to animation:

```
animate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        centre_leftanimate.setVisibility(View.GONE);   // I wants to make the visibility of view to gone,but this is not working                                                         
        half_left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

How to make the visibility of animated view to be invisible after the end of animation?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 25):

I had the very same issue, except I actually removed the view being animated, but the animation persisted!

The simple solution is to actually cancel the animation, then you can hide or remove the view.

```
animatedView.getAnimation().cancel();
```

or if you still have your animation object:

```
animation.cancel();
```

EDIT: There seem to be some left over with the above solution, so I added this:

```
animatedView.setAnimation(null);
```

Comment: why don't we just call animatedView.clearAnimation(); instead?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and in my case removing

```
android:fillAfter="true"
```

in the animation responsible for removing view and this code solve my problem. But others will have better code.

```
viewToHide.startAnimation(animationForHide);
viewToHide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I encountered this issue today and I wanted to show how I solved it, because although the answers already posted helped, none of them was perfectly working for my case.

In my case I created a custom view dinamically, applied 2 animations (alpha and translation) and removed the view after the animations were done. This is how I did it:

```
//Create fade out animation
AlphaAnimation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
fadeOut.setFillAfter(true);
//Create move up animation
TranslateAnimation moveUp = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -getHeight() / 6);
moveUp.setDuration(1000);
moveUp.setFillAfter(true);
//Merge both animations into an animation set
AnimationSet animations = new AnimationSet(false);
animations.addAnimation(fadeOut);
animations.addAnimation(moveUp);
animations.setDuration(1000);
animations.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            //Hide the view after the animation is done to prevent it to show before it is removed from the parent view
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //Create handler on the current thread (UI thread)
            Handler h = new Handler();
            //Run a runnable after 100ms (after that time it is safe to remove the view)
            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    removeView(view);
                }
            }, 100);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
    });
view.startAnimation(animations);
```

Note that this was done inside a custom view (which extended a FrameLayout), everything runs on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Visibility of your View when you want.
If you set it to View.INVISIBLE right after the start of the animation, the animation will be visible, and the View will disappear as soon as the animation stops.
I think that the problem with your code could be that you are using GONE instead of INVISIBLE.
The second problem might be that you start the animation before setting the listener, but with my solution you don't need actually any listener.
Also, take away the FillAfter option.

```
 TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,-rlImages.getWidth()/2,0,0);
 animate.setDuration(1000);
 centre_leftanimate.startAnimation(animate);
 centre_leftanimate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: It tried with Invisible in onAnimationEnd,but still its not working.My animated view is present at the same place where the animation ends.I want that moving animation view to be invisible after the end of animation.

Comment: Did you remove the setFillAfter(true)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolve this problem with the answer of this question [Android - remove View when its animation finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180592/android-remove-view-when-its-animation-finished).

EDIT:
You can do something like that :

```
final MenuActivity MN= MenuActivity.this;
    AFade.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            }           
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            }           
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                LayoutMain.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run () {
                        // it works without the runOnUiThread, but all UI updates must 
                        // be done on the UI thread
                        MN.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                LayoutMain.removeView(NextButton);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

LayoutMain is the layout that contain the view.
MN is your activity.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

just call inside onAnimationEnd

```
animate.setListener(null)
```